# How can I highlight a bar in ChartJS when selected in the legend?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to change background color of bar when selected it in the legend. When I updated chart with `ci.update()` color is reset.

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
                onClick: function (e, legendItem, legend) {
                    const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
                    const ci = legend.chart;
                    const meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
                    const element = meta.data[0];


                    if (!legendItem.checked) {
                        element.options.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)';
                        legendItem.lineWidth = 2;
                        legendItem.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0, 1)';
                        legendItem.checked = true;
                    } else {
                        legendItem.checked = false;
                    }

                    ci.update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the chart.update() is invoked, the chart is re-configuring itself starting from `chart.data.datasets` and all element options (changed in the meanwhile) are lost.
The `chart.data.datasets` must be changed.
The original `backgroundColor`s must be stored because otherwise they will be lost.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const backgroundColors = ['rgba(40, 139, 170, 1)', 'rgba(40, 139, 0, 1)'];
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'Fabruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'user 1 online',
            data: [50, 35, 45, 47, 10, 3, 27],
            backgroundColor: backgroundColors[0],
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderSkipped: 'start'
        },
        {
            label: 'user 2 online',
            data: [50, 35, 45, 47, 10, 3, 27],
            backgroundColor: backgroundColors[1],
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderSkipped: 'start'
        }]
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'right',
          onClick: function (e, legendItem, legend) {
            const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
            const ci = legend.chart;
            const dataset = ci.data.datasets[index];
            if (!dataset.checked) {
              dataset.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)';
              dataset.borderWidth = 2;
              dataset.borderColor = 'rgba(0,0,0, 1)';
              dataset.checked = true;
            } else {
              dataset.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[index]; 
              dataset.borderWidth = 0;
              dataset.borderColor = null;
              dataset.checked = false;
            }
            ci.update();
          }
        }
      }
    }
 });
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! And I have another question. Can I use function
function getHoverColor(value) {
  return isPatternOrGradient(value)
    ? value
    : index_esm(value).saturate(0.5).darken(0.1).hexString();
}
To change color like we hover on bar?

Comment: Yes I think so. But you should be sure that the value (I thick the "hoverBackgroundColor" option) has been set previously in the "chart.data.datasets". I see "index_esm" but maybe you are referring to "color" exposed function of "Chart.helpers".